# No me funciona el código de aumentar puntos en el juego de piedra, papel y tijera

Tags: python, python-3.x

En el código que puse no aumenta las veces que gana la maquina o el jugador, en el jugador y maquina le puse en la variable 0, después en el código if y elif le puse que aumentara 1 puntos más cada vez que ganara la maquina o el jugador. Pero no aumenta los puntos ni del jugador ni la maquina, aquí le dejo el código:

```
import random

bienvenida = ("BIENVENID@ AL JUEGO PIEDRA, PAPEL Y TIJERA")

print(bienvenida.center(50, "="))

escoger = input("Escribe piedra, papel o tijera: ")

juego = ["piedra", "papel", "tijera"]

aleatorio = random.choice(juego)

comienzo = (escoger + " contra " + aleatorio)

jugador = 0

maquina = 0

print(comienzo)

if escoger == "tijera" and aleatorio == "tijera":
 print("empate")

elif escoger == "tijera" and aleatorio == "piedra":
   sumar_maquina = (maquina + 1)
   print("gana piedra")
   print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)

elif escoger == "tijera" and aleatorio == "papel":
   sumar_jugador = (jugador + 1)
   print("gana tijera")
   print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)

elif escoger == "piedra" and aleatorio == "piedra":
   print("empate")
   print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)

elif escoger == "piedra" and aleatorio == "tijera":
   sumar_jugador2 = (jugador + 1)
   print("gana piedra")
   print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)

elif escoger == "piedra" and aleatorio == "papel":
   sumar_maquina2 = (maquina + 1)
   print("gana papel")
   print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)

elif escoger == "papel" and aleatorio == "papel":
   print("empate")
   print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)

elif escoger == "papel" and aleatorio == "tijera":
   sumar_maquina3 = (maquina + 1)
   print("gana tijera")
   print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)

elif escoger == "papel" and aleatorio == "piedra":
   sumar_jugador3 = (jugador + 1)
   print("gana papel")
   print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)
else:
   print("Esa no es una opción valida")

input()
```

Además el resultado de las puntaciones que puse al final del elif, no sale tampoco y no marca el marcador que va ganando la maquina o el juegador, acá dejo cuando imprimo el código:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: No incrementan los puntos porque estas creando variable nuevas en cada `if` utiliza las que ya tienes, por ejemplo para máquina: `maquina = maquina + 1` o si lo deseas reducir puedes hacer `maquina +=1` lo mismo sería para el jugador.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cuando hay que escribir mucho código repetitivo, es hora de buscar una formulación distinta del problema. En lugar de tantos "if" y comparaciones, usare esta matriz:

```
# piedra  papel tijera
puntaje = [[0, -1, 1],
           [1, 0, -1],
           [-1, 1, 0]]
```

Cada fila corresponde a una elección del jugador: piedra, papel y tijera. A cada alternativa se le asigna un valor 0, 1, o -1.

Dentro de cada fila tengo el resultado de comparar el jugador contra la máquina. La fila me da los resultados contra piedra, papel y tijera.

La primera fila contiene un 0 (piedra contra piedra), un -1 (piedra contra papel) y 1 (piedra contra tijera).

Entonces, teniendo la jugada ("papel", 1) y la máquina ("piedra", 0), la entrada en la tabla `puntaje[1][0]` me da '1', que significa que gana el jugador.

Para los puntajes tengo dos variables:

```
jugador = 0
maquina = 0
```

Este diccionario me sirve para asignar un valor numérico a la elección del jugador

```
alternativas = {
    "piedra": 0,
    "papel": 1,
    "tijera": 2
}
```

y esta lista sirve para obtener el nombre asociado a una alternativa

```
llave = ["piedra", "papel", "tijera"]
```

y también un ciclo infinito para probar cada solución:

```
while True:
    escoger = input("Escribe piedra, papel o tijera: ")
    aleatorio = random.randint(0, 2)
    comienzo = (escoger + " contra " + llave[aleatorio])
    print(comienzo)

    resultado = puntaje[alternativas[escoger]][aleatorio]

    if resultado == 0:
        print("empate")
    elif resultado == 1:
        print("gana jugador")
        jugador += 1
    elif resultado == -1:
        print("gana máquina")
        maquina += 1

    print(f"Jugador {jugador}, Máquina {maquina}")
```

No quedo muy bonito, pero funciona.

**Demo**

```
import random

bienvenida = ("BIENVENID@ AL JUEGO PIEDRA, PAPEL Y TIJERA")
print(bienvenida.center(50, "="))

jugador = 0
maquina = 0
           # piedra  papel tijera
puntaje = [[0, -1, 1],
           [1, 0, -1],
           [-1, 1, 0]]
alternativas = {
    "piedra": 0,
    "papel": 1,
    "tijera": 2
}
llave = ["piedra", "papel", "tijera"]

while True:
    escoger = input("Escribe piedra, papel o tijera: ")
    aleatorio = random.randint(0, 2)
    comienzo = (escoger + " contra " + llave[aleatorio])
    print(comienzo)

    resultado = puntaje[alternativas[escoger]][aleatorio]

    if resultado == 0:
        print("empate")
    elif resultado == 1:
        print("gana jugador")
        jugador += 1
    elif resultado == -1:
        print("gana máquina")
        maquina += 1

    print(f"Jugador {jugador}, Máquina {maquina}")
```

produce:

```
====BIENVENID@ AL JUEGO PIEDRA, PAPEL Y TIJERA====
Escribe piedra, papel o tijera: piedra
piedra contra tijera
gana jugador
Jugador 1, Máquina 0
Escribe piedra, papel o tijera: papel
papel contra tijera
gana máquina
Jugador 1, Máquina 1
```

etc.

Comment: No entedi bien tu puntuación de 0, 1, -1

Comment: @nekordemon. El cero corresponde a un empate, el uno significa gana jugador y el -1, que pierde el jugador. Con solo mirar el valor en la matriz sabes quién ganó.

Answer (score 0):

como te indican en varios lugares, cambiando
**sumar_maquina = (maquina + 1)**  por  **maquina += 1**
y
**sumar_jugador3 = (jugador + 1)**  por  **jugador += 1**
tu código debe funcionar, por si te sirve, dejo una versión con los **if** simplificados.

```
import random

bienvenida = ("BIENVENID@ AL JUEGO PIEDRA, PAPEL Y TIJERA")

print(bienvenida.center(50, "="))

escoger = input("Escribe piedra, papel o tijera: ")

juego = ["piedra", "papel", "tijera"]

aleatorio = random.choice(juego)

comienzo = (escoger + " contra " + aleatorio)

jugador = 0

maquina = 0

print(comienzo)

if escoger == "piedra" or escoger == "papel" or escoger == "tijera"
  if escoger == aleatorio:
    print("empate")
    print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)

  elif escoger == "piedra" and aleatorio == "tijera" or escoger == "tijera" and aleatorio == "papel" or escoger == "papel" and aleatorio == "piedra":
    jugador += 1
    print("gana " + escoger)
    print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)

  else: 
    maquina += 1
    print("gana " + aleatorio)
    print("jugador " + jugador + " maquina " + maquina)

else:
   print("Esa no es una opción valida")
input()
```

Answer (score -1):

El problema es que las variables que creas en los ifs solo sirven para dentro de esos ifs asi que no se guarda su resultado. Podrias usar las variables de maquina y de jugador como marcador. Una posible solucion sería esta

```
    import random


    bienvenida = ("BIENVENID@ AL JUEGO PIEDRA, PAPEL Y TIJERA")
    
    print(bienvenida.center(50, "="))
    
    escoger = input("Escribe piedra, papel o tijera: ")
    
    juego = ["piedra", "papel", "tijera"]
    
    aleatorio = random.choice(juego)
    
    comienzo = (escoger + " contra " + aleatorio)
    
    puntuacionJugador = 0
    
    puntuacionMaquina = 0
    
    print(comienzo)
    
    if escoger == "tijera" and aleatorio == "tijera":
     print("empate")
    
    elif escoger == "tijera" and aleatorio == "piedra":
       puntuacionMaquina += 1
       print("gana piedra")
       print("jugador " + puntuacionJugador + " maquina " + puntuacionMaquina )
    
    elif escoger == "tijera" and aleatorio == "papel":
       puntuacionJugador += 1
       print("gana tijera")
       print("jugador " + puntuacionJugador + " maquina " + puntuacionMaquina )
    
    elif escoger == "piedra" and aleatorio == "piedra":
       print("empate")
       print("jugador " + puntuacionJugador + " maquina " + puntuacionMaquina )
    
    elif escoger == "piedra" and aleatorio == "tijera":
       puntuacionJugador += 1
       print("gana piedra")
       print("jugador " + puntuacionJugador + " maquina " + puntuacionMaquina )
    
    elif escoger == "piedra" and aleatorio == "papel":
       puntuacionMaquina += 1
       print("gana papel")
       print("jugador " + puntuacionJugador + " maquina " + puntuacionMaquina )
    
    elif escoger == "papel" and aleatorio == "papel":
       print("empate")
       print("jugador " + puntuacionJugador + " maquina " + puntuacionMaquina )
    
    elif escoger == "papel" and aleatorio == "tijera":
       puntuacionMaquina += 1
       print("gana tijera")
       print("jugador " + puntuacionJugador + " maquina " + puntuacionMaquina )
    
    elif escoger == "papel" and aleatorio == "piedra":
       puntuacionJugador += 1
       print("gana papel")
       print("jugador " + puntuacionJugador + " maquina " + puntuacionMaquina )
    else:
       print("Esa no es una opción valida")
    
    input()
```

Perdón si así no se escribe, no se Python pero se puede entender

Comment: El código que publicas no es válido; la variable "jugador" no está definida. ¿Probastes el código o simplemente lo copiastes sin entender?

Comment: No es que no entienda es que esta creando variables dentro de los ifs y deberian de ser globales para que se guarden los resultados y el resultado no siempre sea 1. Copie el codio y las hice globales

Comment: Entonces cuando dice sumar_maquina = maquina + 1 a que se refiere? Explicamelo y asi apredo gracias

Comment: Vale, se puede ser mas amable

Comment: Hola @fantasticmaceta, tu respuesta es básicamente correcta, solo que renombraste **jugador** por **puntuacionJugador**, y maquina** por **puntuacionMaquina**, pero dentro de las sentencias que imprimen, olvidaste modificarlas, solo corrige eso y quedará perfecta.

Comment: Muchas gracias lo modifico ahora mismo‍